# Value from Variable View on Pydev is not complete

Tags: pydev

I tried to debug a python module, I saw in the Variables view that the value of a variable is not complete. 
This ends with "...".  I think this means that the string was truncated.

In the Details pane from Variable view I set to display the Max Length of the variable (0=unlimited) but also in the Details pane the variable ends with "...".

Why the variable don't have the full value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this means that the string was truncated.

That value is hardcoded in pydevd -- it can be changed manually be editing `eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.core/pysrc/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py -- MAX_IO_MSG_SIZE` in your install.

Now, usually this isn't a real problem because it's possible to just use the console during the debug session and print the variable in the console to view its full values (see: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_debugger.html -- search for `console evaluation` there).

Comment: This also applies to the remote debugger ?

Comment: Yes, this should also work in the remote debugger (you should be able to use the console from the remote debugger to issue commands, but remember that you have to pass `stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True` to see the output as explained in http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html)

Comment: I succeeded to print the whole value in Pydev Debug Console and also I changed the value of the MAX_IO_MSG_SIZE constant and I sync pysrc on the remote debugger but the variable still have just 1000 characters. I used the pydevd 6.2 plugin.

Comment: Do you know why the value of variable still have 1000 characters even if I modified the constant to have 5000 characters?